# MySQL - Combining multiple selects from same table into one result table with a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

I have a table of meter readings which holds a meterNo, readingValue and readingDate.

I want to show the total sum of readingValue per meterNo per year.

For example:

```
SELECT meterNo, SUM(readingValue) '2009' FROM readings
WHERE readingDate >= '2009-01-01' AND readingDate <= '2009-12-31'
GROUP BY meterNo;
```

Will display the table:

```
   meterNo  2009
   --------------
     4       50
     5       5
     12      30
     13      63
     18      18
     26      484
     27      21
     28      510
     29      28
```

Which is what I want, it shows the total reading value for each meter in 2009. However, I need the result table to display a column for each year. So it would be something like this:

```
   meterNo  2009  2010  2011  2012
   --------------------------------
     1             20    35     50
     2                   45     35
     3                   50     60
     4       50    35    20     30
     5       5     10    10     15
     6                          30
```

And so on...

I can reuse the where part of the query:

```
WHERE readingDate >= '2009-01-01' AND readingDate <= '2009-12-31'
```

And just change the date for each year, butt how do I display each WHERE result as its own column in the one result table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL does not have a PIVOT function but you can convert the rows of data into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

If you have a limited number of `years`, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select meterNo,
  sum(case when year(readingDate) = 2009 then readingValue else 0 end) `2009`,
  sum(case when year(readingDate) = 2010 then readingValue else 0 end) `2010`,
  sum(case when year(readingDate) = 2011 then readingValue else 0 end) `2011`,
  sum(case when year(readingDate) = 2012 then readingValue else 0 end) `2012`,
  sum(case when year(readingDate) = 2013 then readingValue else 0 end) `2013`
from readings
group by meterno;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbb1c/1)

But if you are going to have an unknown number of values or what the query to adjust as new years are added to the database, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN year(readingDate) = ',
      year(readingDate),
      ' THEN readingValue else 0 END) AS `',
      year(readingDate), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM readings;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT meterno, ', @sql, ' 
            from readings
            group by meterno');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbb1c/3). Both give the result:

```
| METERNO | 2009 | 2010 | 2012 | 2013 | 2011 |
----------------------------------------------
|       1 |   90 |  180 |    0 |   90 |   90 |
|       2 |   50 |    0 |   90 |    0 |    0 |
|       3 |   80 |   40 |   90 |   90 |    0 |
```

As a side note, if you want `null` to display in the rows without values instead of the zeros, then you can remove the `else 0` (see [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbbb1c/6))

Comment: We've got similar answers.

Comment: @bozdoz Actually our answers are very different, your version is using an `int` for the year, while I am deciphering the year based on `datetime` data. Not only that, I included a dynamic version of the query to allow for an unknown number of years.

Comment: I see you have done that at the end @bluefeet.  I used int for the year just for simplicity's sake for my test example.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I went with as it makes use of year() which is something I can use later in this report. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CASE WHEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to do this.  It allows you to sum multiple values based on multiple conditions.  In your example, you could do something like this (I've simplified my example because I don't have access to your actual data):

```
SELECT meterNo, 
sum(CASE WHEN readingDate = 2009 THEN readingValue END) as '2009',
sum(CASE WHEN readingDate = 2010 THEN readingValue END) as '2010',
sum(CASE WHEN readingDate = 2011 THEN readingValue END) as '2011',
sum(CASE WHEN readingDate = 2012 THEN readingValue END) as '2012'
FROM readings
GROUP BY meterNo
```

You need to switch up the conditions with your own--`sum(CASE WHEN readingDate >= '2009-01-01' AND readingDate <= '2009-12-31' THEN readingValue END)`, etc--but it should work.  Here's a working example that I did on sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6990e/29.  Output is five columns with sums of each meterNo.

Comment: I'm upvoting this version because it returns NULLs as suggested by the blanks in the OP's question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect that, given a bit of common sense (which is usually lacking on SO), zeros would be more appropriate in a report  such as this.

Comment: @phil - Maybe, or maybe not. A NULL is a NULL is a NULL. It conveys the absense of data, which is useful for differentiating between 0 (no movement) and absense of data (not yet commissioned).  Everyone's guessing only

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Very true. You will have seen me on DBA.se, so know that I know :P Maybe it's just me, but reports with blanks instead of zeros don't look right most of the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    meterNo, SUM(readingValue) AS `total`, YEAR(readingDate)
FROM 
    readings
GROUP BY 
    meterNo, YEAR(readingDate);
```

result:

```
METERNO     TOTAL   YEAR(READINGDATE)
1           90      2009
1           90      2010
2           50      2009
3           80      2009
3           40      2010
```

Also note how you can use `YEAR` function instead of the where clause you have.

[SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ff1/1/0)